# URL verification php

Tags: php, regex

The task is to find if the string starts with http:// or https:// or ftp://

$regex = "((https?|ftp)://)?";

but preg_match($regex) does not work correctly. What should I change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a delimiter (/) around the RegExp :)

```
// Protocol's optional
$regex = "/^((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?/";
// protocol's required
$regex = "/^(https?|ftp)\:\/\//";

if (preg_match($regex, 'http://www.google.com')) {
    // ...
}
```

http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1):

Is it necessary to use regex?  One could achieve the same thing using string functions:

```
if (strpos($url, 'http://')  === 0 ||
    strpos($url, 'https://') === 0 ||
    strpos($url, 'ftp://')   === 0)
{
    // do magic
}
```

Comment: Nah.. RegExp is much more fast & stable :)

Comment: I really hope you are joking.

Comment: No i'm not: http://dreamfall.blogspot.com/2008/02/php-benchmarks-strpos-vs-pregmatchall.html

Comment: @TiuTalk - (Forgetting the dubious benchmark speed results for now.) What do you mean by "more stable"? And do you think a regex is easier to read and maintain, especially for someone who has to go to SO or some forum every time he needs to change his code?

Answer (score 0):

You need: `preg_match ('#((https?|ftp)://)?#', $url)`

The `#` delimiters remove the need to escape `/`, which is more convenient for URLs

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$search_for = array('http', 'https', 'ftp');
$scheme = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME);
if (in_array($scheme, $search_for)) {
    // etc.
}
```